# Can I use Canon & Tokina lenses with my Nikon DS3100?

Tags: lens-mount

I have a Nikon DS3100.  I have now been given two lenses.

Canon Zoom Lens EF 35-80MM
TOKINA 28-210MM

I have not yet tried them on my Nikon DS3100 and wondered if they are suitable to use.

Any help would be appreciated.  But please talk in layman terms as I'm not well up on camera and lenses as yet.

Thank you

Comment: Nikon D3100 or Nikon S3100? I'm guessing D. Not that it matters much because a Canon mount lens isn't compatible with a Nikon mount camera.

Comment: DS3100.  Are you saying they are no good with my camera - if so I will sell them

Comment: @Pam There is no such camera as a Nikon DS3100, so if your camera *actually* says that on it, it's a bad fake.

Answer (score 0):

Canon and Nikon lens fittings are not interchangeable due to different fittings and sizing.

Unless the lenses have been loaned to you then the best advice would be to sell them both and buy the equivalent lenses with Nikon fittings (assuming the Tokina is a Canon compatible version.)